# running ./install as root

Tags: software-installation, root

I mounted an .iso file and want to run the install file on it which is going fine. Then, at some point, the installer tries to make a new folder to install the program in. This, however, seems not to be possible. It just says `failed to create folder...`. I  think this is probably due to the installer not having root privileges. I tried running sudo ./install in which case it says:

```
sudo: ./install: command not found.
```

I also tried running gksu ./install in which case it asks for my password in a separate window and then proceeds to do nothing. I just see the terminal with nothing going on. Can anyone tell me how I can run the install as root?

EDIT: Something weird may  be going on. When I do ls I see the correct contents of the mounted disk. Then when I start typing sudo inst and press tab to autocomplete I see a list of files that are not in the mounted disk. Perhaps in some deeper

EDIT2: ls output

```
activate.ini  help                  install_guide.pdf  readme.txt
archives      install               java               sys
bin           installer_input.txt   license.txt        trademarks.txt    
etc           InstallForMacOSX.app  patents.txt        version.txt
```

EDIT3: its a christmas miracle, it works! I added the command exec to mount as exucutive and then did su - in the terminal and proceeded to install with no problems. Thanks so much everybody!

Comment: Did you run `sudo ./install` from the directory where the `install` script is located? What operating system are you running?

Comment: yes I did, when I just did ./install it worked but as soon as I used sudo in front of it it gave me that message. I am using mint 17

Comment: Have you tried `sudo /full/path/to/install` ?

Comment: I will try it, however the install file is on a mounted archive so the path to it is pretty crazy weird

Comment: @Slugger `sudo "$PWD/install"` will probably do that, if you're currently in that directory. But what do you mean by "mounted archive"? That may be the actual cause of the problem, at least if you don't just mean `mount -o loop`

Comment: I right clicked my .iso file and clicked 'mount archive' Maybe this is part of the problem, I am a little new to Linux like my original title said.

Comment: @Slugger In that case, what makes you so sure you ran the `./install` from the correct directory? It sounds like you ran both from your home directory instead.

Comment: well when in the file browser i click on the file under devices. then I right click and open terminal here. Also when I do ls i see the install file there.

Comment: @Slugger did any of our suggestions help?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I tried all commands that were suggested, I also copied the contents of the disk to a folder in my home folder and tried to run install from there but that also does not work I am afraid. If anybody has any other ideas that would be great and thanks for the awesome help so far !

Comment: @Slugger ah... please add that 'add exec to the mount options' you found as an answer (yes, it's OK to answer your own question.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like for some reason, your `sudo` is not configured to run from the directory you launch it it. I don't know how or why that should be the case but you can try these alternatives (for the sake of these examples, I am assuming your ISO is mounted at `/home/slugger/iso`, change that to the actual path of the mount point):

1. Use the full path

   ```
   sudo /home/slugger/iso/install
   ```
2. Export your environment to `sudo` with the `-E` option.

   ```
   cd /home/slugger/iso/install
   sudo -E ./install
   ```
3. Start a root shell session and do it from there

   ```
   sudo -i
   cd /home/slugger/iso/install
   ./install
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo -i
   /home/slugger/iso/install
   ```

Comment: This is the default behavior.  Explicitly calling /bin/sh as in my answer below will circumvent the export.

Comment: @eyoung100 1) It is not the default on any system I am familiar with, what are you running? 2) Yes, your solution will also work assuming that the script is written in the language of whatever shell your `/bin/sh` happens to be but that's a pretty major assumption. `/bin/sh` can be POSIX-bash, or `dash` or any number of things. On mint, it's `dash` I think in which case, a bash script using bashisms is likely to fail.

Comment: On Gentoo, bin/sh is pointed to BASH.  I have never used the full path implementation, and although I know it works, I advise against it, because if the script you run generates output, the output gets created in the directory you called the full path from, which is why the default is to use the current directory.  AFAIK, all make scripts assume your shell is BASH, because every script I've run or wrote has a shebang as the first line, i.e I can start the script with bash but the shebang points to the correct interpreter.

Comment: @eyoung100 yes, but 1) calling `bash` as `sh` makes it run in POSIX mode 2) I quite agree that most configure shells are written in `sh` (I even said so in my edit to your A) but that doesn't mean that all are. I have never seen one that isn't, but you never know. 3) In any case, that's beside the point since the script is _not_ a configure script but some kind of `install` script. 4) You make a good point about output being created in PWD and how that can be a problem but, again, I don't know that that's relevant to this `install` script.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Mounting the ISO.
2. cd to Mount Point
3. `sudo sh install` or `sudo sh install.(prefix)`

That calls `sh` (the default shell) with the `install` script as a parameter, it should be able to run the script correctly as long as it is an `sh` script (most such scripts are).

Comment: I get the following message: sh: 0: Can't open install.sh

Comment: Can you clarify your last paragraph? Cite a reference or demonstrate what you mean by it?

Comment: What makes you think that `./` is an alias? An alias to what exactly? It's just a path and `.` is defined as the [current directory](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266) by POSIX. Again, nothing to do with `sh`.

Comment: `./` is a normal path, not a shell alias. Each directory---even an empty one---has two entries: `.` (current) and `..` (parent). So `./install` is a relative path; lookup starts by going into `.` (i.e., current directory) and then looking for `install`.

Comment: Oh I see what he's thinking. The dot in `./` is the `.` when you do `ls -la`. This tells the system to run the program that's in the current directory, i.e. `.`.

Comment: Does the install script have an extension?  I've always thought of `./` as an alias to sh because it is always used for shell scripts.  The true answer is the #! in the script.

Comment: No, `.` just means the current directory so `./` is just a path. Nothing at all to do with `sh` or any other shell. You see it often when the scripts in question are in the current directory and that is not in the user's `$PATH`.

Comment: @eyoung100 That's because when you put a name without a path (no `/`) at the shell prompt, the shell looks in `$PATH` to find it.  When you provide a path, the shell looks at that particular location. So `./foo` makes it look in the current directory; but so would `/home/anthony/whatever/foo`. Or a bunch of other ways of specifying that path.

Comment: @eyoung100 - to show what's happening try this: `ls ./`. You'll see the current dir. If it were an alias to sh then who knows what would happen 8-)

Comment: I assume that was directed to me, I did ls ./ and it gives me a list of files including the install file that I need. Also, in the original answer what do I fill for prefix?

Comment: @Slugger no, that was directed at eyoung100 who had misunderstood the meaning of `./`. Running `ls` won't help here, though running `sudo ls ./` would presumably indicate sudo's not not where you are.

Comment: sudo ls ./ doesnt work it says permission denied

Comment: can you update your post with the output of `ls` please?

Comment: i will do that right now

Comment: Try `sudo sh install` from the directory where `install` resides

Comment: it doesnt work. It says:
sh: 0: Can't open install

Comment: Then you need to copy the contents from the CD to your home directory and try the command again.

Comment: It gives me this...Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
install: 1: eval: /tmp/mathworks_4229/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
Finished

Comment: That proves the installer now works... Now you need to contact mathworks and ask them how to make the installer use your system version of java instead of the bundled version on the CD.